# Unable to read payload from POST req to API G/W endpoint triggering Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

have a 3rd party application in which I have subscribed my AWS API Gateway endpoint URL so that whenever an event occurs in my 3rd party application, that should trigger my API gateway endpoint which eventually is a trigger for my Lambda function.

In my lambda function I want to read event payload and send that to some other application.

Currently, I am unable to read event data in my lambda function.

POST Request from Postman:
https://16f89u5f9b.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/default/test123?name=postmanName&city=postmanCity&time=postmanTime&day=postmanDay

API Gateway endpoint :
https://16f89u5f9b.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/default/test123

This API gateway is a trigger for my lambda function.

Response in Postman:
{
"message": "Good LambdaTime, postmanName of postmanCity. Happy LambdaDay!",
"input": {
"resource": "/test123",
"path": "/test123",
"httpMethod": "POST",
"headers": {
}

```js
'use strict';
console.log('Loading hello world function');
 
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    let name = "LambdaName";
    let city = 'LambdaCity';
    let time = 'LambdaTime';
    let day = 'LambdaDay';
    let responseCode = 200;
    console.log("request: " + JSON.stringify(event));
    
    if (event.queryStringParameters && event.queryStringParameters.name) {
        console.log("Received name: " + event.queryStringParameters.name);
        name = event.queryStringParameters.name;
    }
    
    if (event.queryStringParameters && event.queryStringParameters.city) {
        console.log("Received city: " + event.queryStringParameters.city);
        city = event.queryStringParameters.city;
    }
    
    if (event.headers && event.headers['day']) {
        console.log("Received day: " + event.headers.day);
        day = event.headers.day;

    }
    
    if (event.body) {
        let body = JSON.parse(event.body)
        if (body.time) 
            time = body.time;
    }
 
    let greeting = `Good ${time}, ${name} of ${city}.`;
    if (day) greeting += ` Happy ${day}!`;

    let responseBody = {
        message: greeting,
        input: event
    };
    
    // The output from a Lambda proxy integration must be 
    // in the following JSON object. The 'headers' property 
    // is for custom response headers in addition to standard 
    // ones. The 'body' property  must be a JSON string. For 
    // base64-encoded payload, you must also set the 'isBase64Encoded'
    // property to 'true'.
    let response = {
        statusCode: responseCode,
        headers: {
            "x-custom-header" : "my custom header value"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(responseBody)
    };
    console.log("response: " + JSON.stringify(response))
    return response;
};
```

Comment: Please show your code. Detail what you have tried, and what errors you are receiving.

Comment: @MarkB Thanks for checking on this. I have attached my lambda function code, API Gateway trigger Endpoint and Response output in Postman has been added into description. Please check and help me.